# Arithmetic Shift Not Working

Tags: verilog

I am trying to use the Verilog Arithmetic Shift, where the bits shift to the right and get rotated to the start of the binary number again. For example, if I have `0110b`, an arithmetic rotation of 2 would result in `1001b`.

In Verilog, this is done with the `>>>` operator, but for some reason this doesn't work:

```
module arithmeticShift(input [0:3] in, output [0:4] out);
    assign {out} = in >>> 2;
endmodule
```

What am I doing wrong? If I input `0011b`, I get `0000b` instead of `1100b`.

Comment: You're confusing *arithmetic shift* with *circular shift*. Arithmetic shift just preserves the sign of the value under shifting, it does not recirculate the shifted bits back in from the other side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside using >> you can try this:

```
out[2:0] = in[3:1]
out[3] = in[0]
```

**Note:**
I found something wrong here arithmeticShift(input **[0:3]** in, output **[0:4]** out);

Answer (score 0):

It's because the arithmetic shift does not wrap around.

if you move 0011 two places to the right, the 1's drop off the end:

0011 - original

0001 - >>> 1

0000 - >>> 2

If you were to shift left 2 places, you would get:

1100.

Try using >> instead as Tim's comment says, you're mixing up the two shifts.

Comment: Alright, then I will have to do a circular shift instead of an arithmetic one. I thought they were the same thing. Is there a pre-made way to do this in Verilog?

Comment: `>>` makes logical shift.